# HTML interaction with blockchain

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I'm collecting temperature data from user on-chain. However, since cant get exact (live) time through my html code connected via testrpc to the blockchain I do so.

Where post click a button, html code complies to starts sensing and recording data as well as displaying time of so.

My question here is, is there a way where I can for example send an email with a screen shot of the html page since it has the data needed as well as time? Or save it locally as a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) to send email and for the screenshot can use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) or can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828187/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-html-with-javascript) answer